# Find a way to calculate $f(x) = x-\sqrt{x^2-\alpha}, \alpha << x.$

Tags: numerical-methods

I thought about this but I could not come up with a way to calculate this. Any comment?? note:$x$ is much larger than $\alpha$

Answer (score 1):

Write $\sqrt{x^2-a}$ as $\vert x \vert \sqrt{1-\dfrac{a}{x^2}}$. Now recall that
$$(1-y)^{1/2} = 1-\dfrac{y}2-\dfrac{y^2}{8}-\dfrac{y^3}{16}-\dfrac{5 y^4}{128} + \mathcal{O}(y^5)$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the binomial theorem:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\sqrt{x^2-\alpha}}x&=\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{x^2}\right)^{1/2}\\\\
&=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{1/2}k(-1)^k\left(\frac{\alpha}{x^2}\right)^k\\\\
&\approx1-\frac{\alpha}{2x^2}\;,
\end{align*}$$

with more terms readily available if you need them. Here

$$\binom{1/2}k=\frac{(1/2)^{\underline k}}{k!}\;,$$

where $x^{\underline i}$ is a [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol).

Comment: where did you get $\frac{\sqrt{x^2-\alpha}}{x}??$

Comment: @eChung00: You want $x-\sqrt{x^2-\alpha}$. Obviously you can find this (by multiplying by $x$) if you can find $1-\frac{\sqrt{x^2-\alpha}}x$.

Answer (score 0):

For positive $x$, multiply by $\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-\alpha}}{x+\sqrt{x^2+\alpha}}$. We get
$$\frac{\alpha}{x+\sqrt{x^2-\alpha}},$$
which can be computed to good accuracy without roundoff error issues.

Comment: If $x$ is negative, you might have some issue though.

Comment: In the real world, variables tend to be positive. If $x$ is negative, let $y=-x$.